# Issues when attempting to get accounts using the GDAX API

Tags: api, python, gdax

Here is the github I have working with:

https://github.com/danpaquin/gdax-python

When I run the following code:

```
auth_client.get_accounts()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Which doesn't make much sense to me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I assume you have setup API access within your account settings and initialized AuthenticatedClient ?

Comment: yes, i found the problem though, wasnt using the passphrase